# What this usage of '@' in ASP.NET mean

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am learning ASP.NET(C#) and came across this code:

```
<asp:DropDownList
    id="ddlMovieCategory"
    DataSourceID="srcMovieCategories"
    DataTextField="Name"
    DataValueField="Id"
    Runat="server" />

<asp:Button
    id="btnSelect"
    Text="Select"
    Runat="server" />

<asp:GridView
    id="grdMovies"
    DataSourceID="srcMovies"
    CssClass="gridView"
    Runat="server" />

<asp:SqlDataSource
    id="srcMovieCategories"
    SelectCommand="SELECT Id, Name FROM MovieCategories"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Movies %>"
    Runat="server" />

<asp:SqlDataSource
    id="srcMovies"
    SelectCommand="SELECT Title,Director FROM Movies
        WHERE CategoryId=@Id"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Movies %>"
    Runat="server">
    <SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter 
        Name="Id" 
        ControlID="ddlMovieCategory" 
        PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I am wondering How the @ symbol in the last control's SelectCommand work. It works as expected but I don't understand how it gets the value following the @ i.e. if it is to use a variable which is escaped in ASP tag then how does it know that Id refers to the DropDownList's currently selected item.

Edit: I think I might have found the solution. I think it's from this bit of code, Am I correct:

```
<asp:ControlParameter 
    Name="Id" 
    ControlID="ddlMovieCategory" 
    PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
</SelectParameters>
```

Comment: Did you just stop reading the code when you got to the bit you didn’t understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following string

```
"SELECT Title,Director FROM Movies WHERE CategoryId=@Id"
```

represents a parameterized sql query. The value of parameter Id, `@Id`, would be assigned to `CategoryId`, before this query is sent to database, in order to be executed.

Parameterized queries are the first thing we use, in order we avoid [SQL injections](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).